# list of lists to find an element from user input

Tags: python-3.x, list

right now, I'm trying to do a simple program, where user can **add new, view, search,** and **delete**. But as for now, I'm stuck at `def findEmp():` below is my code and I'm really appreciate for you guys to help me with this problem.

When I key in the existing name 'mia' from global list, the result show 'Employee name not exist'.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

emps_global = [['mia','hr','admin']] # existing element
tablehead = ['Name', 'Department', 'Position']

def addnew():
    emp_new = [] # empty local list

    emp_new.append(input("Enter name: "))
    emp_new.append(input("Enter department: "))
    emp_new.append(input("Enter position: "))
    
    emps_global.append(emp_new) # append local list to global list called emps_global
    
    print(emps_global) # print out list of lists for emps_global

def findEmp():
    emp = input("Enter employee name: ") # even existing name in the global list show 'not exist'
    if emp in range(len(emps_global)):   # i'm not sure this is correct or not
        print("Yes employee exist")
    elif emp not in range(len(emps_global)):
        print("Employee name not exist")

def view():
    print(tabulate(emps_global, headers=tablehead, tablefmt='psql'))

def deleteInfo():
    pass

while True:
    print("[1] to add")
    print("[2] to search")
    print("[3] to view")
    print("[4] to delete")
    inp = input(">> ")
    if inp == '1':
        addnew()
    elif inp == '2':
        findEmp()
    elif inp == '3':
        view()
    elif inp == '4':
        deleteInfo()
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit you `findEmp()` as

```
def findEmp():
    emp = input("Enter employee name: ") # even existing name in the global list show 'not exist'
    for entry in emps_global:
        if entry[0]==emp:   # i'm sure this is correct or not
            return entry
    return "Name does not exist"
```

- the range(len(emp_globs)) gives a list of numbers from 0 to len(emp_globs), so your condition compares the input name with a number, hence it doesn't work.

Comment: wow thank you. But how to I can print out let say if user key in name ```mia```, and the result will show ```['mia', 'hr', 'admin']``` because I just print out ```Yes employee exist``` to show me if condition is correct or not.

Comment: I have edited the above code to return the employee details if found, else it returns a message

Comment: Not working because when I key in employee name it not return employee details even though name already in the list. Thanks for your time with my silly request.

Comment: I have tested the code and it is working for me. Make sure you are entering the names in the correct format, i.e. lowercase, spacing,etc

Comment: Yes, I have enter the names in the correct format but it still not return the employee details and one more, what does it mean ```entry[0] == emp:```?

Comment: Since, each record of employees is a list of 3 elements where the first element is the name of the employee, we are looping over all the records and checking the first element to match with the input

Comment: now I can get result as I want, I add print after return ```return print(entry)```

Comment: `print` is not generally used with a return statement. 
A better syntax is `return entry`.
It all depends upon how you are calling the function.
If you call the function as `var=findEmp()`, nothing will be printed on the console but the return value will be saved to var.
If you call the function as `findEmp()`, the return value will be printed on the console

Comment: I'm using vscode, if it just ```return entry``` it won't show the result. What IDE did you use? Ok it works if I'm using python interpreter. So confusing